# Use another version of C++ in Premake

Tags: c++, visual-c++, premake, buildconfiguration

I can't change my C++ version with from the Premake file (i'm using the MSVC toolchain)
This is the lua file i'm running:

```lua
workspace "myname"
    configurations{"Release", "Debug"}
    platforms {"Win64", "Win32"}
    
project "myname"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"
    files {"src/**.pch", "src/**.h", "src/**.cpp"} -- .hpp not included
    buildoptions "--std=c++17"



filter "configurations:Debug"
    defines { "DEBUG" }
    symbols "On"    
    targetdir "bin/Debug"

filter "configurations:Release"
    defines { "NDEBUG" }
    optimize "On"
    symbols "Off"
    targetdir "bin/Release"

filter "platforms:Win64"
    system "windows"
    architecture "x86_64" --x64

filter "platforms:Win32"
    system "windows"
    architecture "x86"
```

It generates the solution, but the version is still the default one from vs (C++11)

Comment: https://premake.github.io/docs/cppdialect/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--std=c++17` is specific to gcc/clang.

It would be `/std=c++17` for msvc

so

```lua
filter "toolset:msc*"
  buildoptions "/std=c++17"
filter "toolset:gcc* or clang*"
  buildoptions "--std=c++17"
filter {}
```

Even like that, it would have caveas, as `buildoptions` is not **displayed** correctly inside visual studio when there is a specific field (so, here, language would still be set to default and that entry would be in extra option), even if options is correctly used.

Fortunately, premake provides [`cppdialect`](https://premake.github.io/docs/cppdialect/) which handles that correctly:

```lua
cppdialect "c++17" -- apply to all toolsets and generators :-)
```